# Why sum() does not have the key arg?

Tags: python, built-in

Today, I automatically wrote some thing like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

s = [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]
sum_x = sum(s, key = lambda foo: foo.x)
```

And got this:

> TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments

Is there any special reason for `sum()` does not have a `key` arg?

Comment: `sum(i.x for i in s)` works just as well.

Comment: why would it need one?

Comment: Yeah... In case that I need a complex function... generator expressions would solve all the situations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you can just write `sum(foo.x for foo in s)` instead.  If you tried to do this with one of the functions that does take a `key` argument (`sorted`, `min`, `max`, etc.), the function would end up returning the key(s) rather than the original item(s), and getting the original items while sorting by keys is tricky enough that Python gives you a built-in way to do that via a keyword argument.

Thus: There's no special reason for `sum` to not take a `key`; rather, those other functions have special reasons why they *do* take a `key`.  `key` is the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `key` argument because `sum()` doesn't return the original elements (like `sorted()`, `min()` and `max()` do). Instead, it just sums the inputs.

If, say, `min()` did not take a `key` argument, it could not return the minimum `Foo()` object based on an attribute; it could only return the value of that attribute. But `sum()` doesn't work that way, it doesn't need to preserve the original objects.

You can easily transform the inputs in a generator expression:

```
sum(item.x for item in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no `key` param, the good news is that You *can* use `sum`
with your `Foo` object! Others have already pointed out that the easiest way to
do this

```
sum(item.x for item in s)
```

However, it's also possible to use it without the comprehension.

## Object addition

In order for sum to work, basic addition needs to work first.

```
In [2]: class Foo:
...:     def __init__(self, x):
...:         self.x = x
...:

In [3]: Foo(3) + Foo(5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f0e9c3a4abb9> in <module>()
----> 1 Foo(3) + Foo(5)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Foo' and 'Foo'
```

We can enable addition by defining the `__add__` method.

```
In [4]: class Foo:
...:     def __init__(self, x):
...:         self.x = x
...:     def __add__(self, other):
...:         return Foo(self.x + other.x)
...:

In [5]: Foo(3) + Foo(5)
Out[5]: <__main__.Foo at 0x102bdc2e8>
```

to make clear that it worked

```
In [6]: result = Foo(3) + Foo(5)

In [7]: result.x
Out[7]: 8
```

But this doesn't solve everything.

```
In [8]: sum([Foo(3), Foo(5)])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-70968119f3ba> in <module>()
----> 1 sum([Foo(3), Foo(5)])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Foo'
```

We didn't try to add an `int`, but the `sum` function thinks we did. What gives?

## THE `sum` FUNCTION

using ipython to inspect the `sum` function, you can see that it includes an
optional `start` parameter

```
In [1]: sum??
Docstring:
sum(iterable[, start]) -> value

Return the sum of an iterable of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the iterable is
empty, return start.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

So according to that, `sum(s)` is the same as `sum(s, 0)` and it's this start
value that is causing the error. All we have to do is replace the start value
with the equivalent `Foo` object

```
In [9]: sum([Foo(3), Foo(5)], Foo(0))
Out[9]: <__main__.Foo at 0x102bdc9e8>

In [10]: result = sum([Foo(3), Foo(5)], Foo(0))

In [11]: result.x
Out[11]: 8
```

This also applies to some other types

```
In [12]: sum([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [])
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

but not all of them

```
In [13]: sum(["abc", "def"], "")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-452a33de0457> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(["abc", "def"], "")

TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```