# sum() takes no keyword arguments ,Python

Tags: scipy, python-3.7

EDIT: I have some codes in python 3.7 as below. It means the codes were on python 2 but I want to reversion in it to Python 3.7.4 . There were imports other libraries and there were some classes my code is in of them:

EDIT:

```
import core
from numpy import *
from scipy.special import sph_jn, sph_jnyn, lpmn
from scipy.misc.common import factorial
#from IPython.Debugger import Tracer; debug_here = 
Tracer()
#from scipy.misc import derivative
from numdifftools import Derivative
from doc_inherit import doc_inherit

...

class Lab:
"""Laboratory class"""

 def __init__(self, particle, alpha, m1=1):
        self.particle = particle.copy()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.m1 = m1
        self.k1 = self.k0 * m1
...

 def __get_amplitude_matrix2(self, c_sca, Theta, phi):
        #debug_here()
        n = len(c_sca[0])
        ms = len(c_sca)
        P = core.get_Pmn(ms - 1, n, cos(self.alpha + Theta))
        PnT = P[:, 0, 1, 1:]
        l = arange(1, n + 1)
        A1 = sum(1j ** (-l) * c_sca[0] * PnT, axis=1) #axes: 0-Theta, 1-l
        A2 = zeros_like(A1)
        sinT = sin(self.alpha + Theta)
        cosT = cos(self.alpha + Theta)
        for m in xrange(1, ms):
            PnT = P[:, 0, m, m:]
            PdnT = P[:, 1, m, m:]
            l = arange(m, n + 1)
            a = c_sca[m][:n - m + 1]
            b = c_sca[m][n - m + 1:]
            A1 -= sinT * cos(m * phi)\
            * sum(1j ** (-l + 1) * (a * PnT + 1j * b * PdnT), axis=1)
            #A2 += m*sin(m*phi)/sinT\
            #     *sum(1j**(-l)*b*Pnt, axis=1)
            A2 += m * sin(m * phi) * cosT\
            * sum(((l - m) * 1j ** (-l)) * b * P[:, 0, m - 1, m:], axis=1)
            A2 += m * sin(m * phi)\
            * sum(((l + m) * 1j ** (-l)) * b * P[:, 0, m - 1, m - 1:size(P, 3) - 1], axis=1)
        # PnT/sinT = null when SinT==0
        # to solve this we can use:
        #   sqrt(1-x**2)P^m_l(x)
        #       = (l-m)xP^{m-1)_l(x) - (l+m)P^{m-1}_{l-1}(x)
        # Here x will be cos(theta), sqrt(1-x**2)=cos(theta)
        return A1, A2
```

when I compile that I get this error:

```
sum() takes no keyword arguments
```

at this line of code:

```
A1 = sum(1j ** (-l) * c_sca[0] * PnT, axis=1) #axes: 0-Theta, 1-l
```

so what should I do and briefly what the error mean?

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: There is a builtin Python `sum` function, and there's a `numpy.sum` function.  Only the `numpy` takes an argument like `axis=1`.

Comment: This is `numpy` one. Where should I edit my code ,means which part make error? In the arguments, at them, my values , before the error line, structure of `sum` , Other passing variables?

Comment: Also I want to know what this error critically mean.I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574541/why-sum-does-not-have-the-key-arg. But it doesn't help much.

Comment: How did you import `numpy`?

Comment: The use of `xrange` means this was written for Py2, and not adapted.  The `sum` error looks like it's using the Python `sum`, not the numpy one.  But the fact that it got past the previous `arange` line, indicates that the `import numpy as *` is work.  If possible I'd rewrite the code to be Py3 compliant, and work with `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Do you understand what `keyword argument` means in Python?  The `axis=1` in the  error line is a keyword argument.  That should be fine with `np.sum`, but not for the builtin Python `sum`.  Your SO link doesn't help much, because those posters wanted a different keyword argument, one modeled on the Python `sort` function.

Comment: It means I must change all `sum` to `np.sum` as the instruction you said , isn't any other way to keep this code without changing details?

Comment: Does `import numpy as *` work for `sum` in Python 3.7 without using `np.sum`?

Comment: Normally the * import would shadow the buitlin `sum`. Since I can't reproduce your imports I can't explore why it appears not to do so.   You could add a `print(sum)` to your code to better identify this function.  Or `print(sum.__doc__)`

Comment: successful . As I changed `sum` to `np.sum` in my above codes , my program works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `xrange` means this was written for Py2, and not adapted. The `sum` error looks like it's using the Python `sum`, not the `numpy` one. But the fact that it got past the previous arange line, indicates that the `import numpy as *` is work. If possible I'd rewrite the code to be Py3 compliant, and work with `import numpy as np`. As changing `sum` to `np.sum` in above codes , it would work.